# Flutter - State management with just Providers package - How to share user data across different provider classes

Tags: flutter, state-management

I am trying to write an app that has authentication and several screens. I need to pass user data (token) to other providers so that they can invoke an authenticated API call by passing token.
I decided to use only Providers package as I found it very simple to use and besides it is recommended by Google.
I am passing multiple providers at the root level and then using it anywhere in the App. I am wondering how do i pass userProvider which holds login response to other providers? e.g., from a widget tree, i can invoke a method on any provider and that method should make an API call using token retrieved from login response. but, my token in inside userProvider.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

save the token you get from the login response in the shared preferences and thus you can access it from anywhere inside your app

Comment: this is my implementation but every time I change to a page that requires user info, I have to await for shared pref to load the data. I am looking for a provider solution.

Comment: Sat the token as a variable inside the provider object and initialize it inside the constructor of the provider and wrap the page that depend on the provider with a future builder and when the token get inisialized , build the page you want otherwise display anything such as progressIndicator or something like this